# how to customize Partner Portal Homepage Components

Tags: visualforce-component, home-page-component, partner-portal

1. I need to remove "recent items" from the Partner Portal homepage.
2. Need to add a custom VF Page component on Portal homepage.

Can anybody help me to achieve this. just basic step's would work !

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove Recent items - You can create a new Home Page Layout and can remove Recent Item option. Assign Home Page layout to Partner Portal Profile.

[image]
2. You can create custom component (Setup--> Home Page Component). 
[image]